# Phi and Pearson's correlation, signs reversed

Tags: correlation

I have two binary variables, naturally dichotomous, yes no
They present information on whether a college has multi-stream recycling or single-stream recycling. I did Pearson's product-moment correlation as I read in a research paper that naturally dichotomous variables can be used in Pearson's correlation. I also did Phi coefficient correlation to see the comparison.
I found that the value of association is the same, but the signs have reversed from negative in Pearson's to positive in phi. I am not able to understand why the signs changed.

Also, additional information, the variables are not exclusive; there are some colleges that have both types of recycling streams. Will that cause a problem in the analysis? Should I re-code these variables?

Answer (score 3):

I think this has to do with how the phi ($\phi$) is calculated and reported by the software you use. Let's use an example and assume that we have a small data set with two dichotomous variables (0=no, 1=yes):

```
ss <- c(0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0) 
ms <- c(1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1)
```

And we want to calculate the Pearson's correlation ($r$) using this [formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_correlation_coefficient):

$$r = \frac{\sum(x_i - \bar x)(y_i - \bar y)}{\sqrt{\sum(x_i-\bar x)^2 \sum(y_i-\bar y)^2}}$$

You can plug the numbers into the formula or simply run the function `cor` in `R`:

```
cor(ss, ms)
-0.5833333
```

As in your case, we have a negative $r$. Now, we can calculate $\phi$ for  $2 \times 2$ contingency table using our two variables:

```
|     | ms |     |
|-----|----|-----|
| ss  | no | yes |
| no  | 1  | 5   |
| yes | 3  | 1   |
```

We can use the formula on this [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phi_coefficient) for $\phi$ coefficient. Let's assign letters to make it simple, and then plug the numbers:

```
|     | ms |     |
|-----|----|-----|
| ss  | no | yes |
| no  | A  | B   |
| yes | C  | D   |
```

$$\phi = \frac{AD-BC}{\sqrt{(A+B)(C+D)(A+C)(B+D)}} = \frac{1-15}{\sqrt{6 \times 4 \times 4 \times 6}} = -0.5833333$$

Exactly the same result. So, why do you have a positive value then? If you google around, you can see a different formula for $\phi$:

$$\phi = \sqrt{\frac{\chi^2}{N}}$$

In fact, this is the formula of [Cramér's V](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram%C3%A9r%27s_V) (sometimes called Cramér's phi, $\phi_c$) simplified for $2 \times 2$ contingency tables. These two measures are related: "In the case of a $2 \times 2$ contingency table Cramér's V is equal to the absolute value of [Phi coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phi_coefficient)." We can check this using our small data, where $\chi^2 \approx 3.403$

$$\phi_c = \sqrt{\frac{3.403}{10}} \approx 0.583 $$

This could explain why you observe a reversal of sign.